# porque mi archivo colors.xml esta incompleto en android studio?

Tags: android

No se por que aparece el archivo colors.xml incompleto, apenas lo instale y no se por que me marca ese archivo y no encuentro librerias o archivos completos para solucionar este problema[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El archivo no tiene información de un colors.xml

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color_name">hex_color</color>
</resources>
```

Si tu no editaste el archivo, el problema se debe a un error de sincronización de los recursos, te sugiero realizar:

`Build` -> `Clean Proyect` y luego `Build` -> `Rebuild Proyect`.

Incluso puedes eliminar los directorios /build de tu proyecto y volver a construirlo nuevamente.